# Why is the difference of my two images blank?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I tried to get the difference of two images. Here are my two images.

[image]

[image]

However, I only got a blank image like this

[image]

I use OpenCV package in python. The code I use is:

```
image3 = image1 - image2
plt.imshow(image3)
plt.show()
```

The backgrounds of the two images are not the same. I don't understand why the difference of the two images is just blank. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try using cv2.absDiff(image1,image2). If you subtract the brighter from the darker as you have, you will get negative values that might be clipped to 0 or black.

Comment: Hello @fmw42, thank you for your reply. I tried it. It does not work. I got the same blank image.

Comment: See my answer below. It works for me! Sorry, the spelling was wrong. It is cv2.absdiff(image1, image2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me in Python/OpenCV using cv2.absdiff(). I suggest you use cv2.imshow() to view your results and cv2.imwrite() to save your results.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('image1.png')
image2 = cv2.imread('image2.png')

diff = cv2.absdiff(image1, image2)
print(np.amin(diff), np.amax(diff))

cv2.imwrite('diff.png', diff)
cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

```
Min and Max Values In Diff:
0 91
```

Comment: Hello @fmw42, thank you so much. It works for me now. I know now why it didn't work for me before. I used imread from skimage to read the image. Do you have an idea why that didn't work?

Comment: No, not off-hand. I would have to use skimage imread and see what is happening. Please show your full code showing your imports and your image reading code along with the difference processing and output